# What is the Russian translation for "brogrammer"?

Tags: перевод

There is [an article about this word in Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brogrammer). But what is the Russian for this word? "говнокодер" and "быдлокодер" are not suitable here (it means good developer, not bad).

An example of using:

*I don't write unit tests, interfaces, use IOC or heavy ORMs. Yet I'm not a brogrammer.*

Comment: this is very dangerous question. One can say - хабралюди - and will be downvoted by crowd )))

Comment: Is there any particular context or the situation when you would like to use the Russian translation of this word? It would be helpful if you could describe it.

Comment: Also, can you explain why do you think that быдлокодер is not suitable at all?

Comment: @shabunc in my experience `быдлокодер` refers to the code quality, not to the programmer's behavior

Comment: быдлокодер at least correlates, since yes, it is not directly indicating programmer's behaviour, but nevertheless, you can make some conclusions. As for the exact translation, I don't believe it exist. You see, to understand brogrammer you have first comprehend `bro`. And as for bro, I hardly can imagine direct translation. Гопник is totally different.  Брателло has  different connotation as well.

Comment: no russian equivalent

Comment: Sorry, but words "говно/быдло-кодер" don't mean a GOOD programmer ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть выражение "погромист", но оно тоже скорее насмешливое, чем серьёзное.

Русского аналога "brogrammist" боюсь что нет.

Comment: Brogrammer тоже насмешливое. «Погромист» подходит. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no Russian equivalent for the word 'brogrammer' since there is no exact equivalent for the word 'bro' (for definitions given at [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bro)).

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE. Please refrain from reposting existing answers unless your expand or explain them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Russian translation. May be "мачо-программист".

Comment: this is irrelevant for two reasons: first, this combinations of words is not actually used, second, brogrammer is not about "machism" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

программист-раздолбай

Comment: You could expand a bit on your answer.  You should know that more expanded answers are better than single-word ones.

Answer (score -1):

браграммист и братанграммист будут не понятны русскому человеку. В нашем языке нет аналога слова brogrammer, однако в рунете широко распространено слово бро ( имеет тот же смысл, что и bro), так что если вы скажете "брограммер", то скорее всего человек вас сможет понять. Но лучше всего сказать "хороший программист", "отличный программист", "хороший программист".

"мачо-программист" поймут как сексуально-активный программист, не используйте такое выражение.

Comment: Валерий, да с чего вы взяли что brogrammer - это хороший программист, отличный программист?

Comment: wow, sorry.  I speak Russian, English I do not know much. Plz tell me, what the brogrammer? It's good programmer or anything else?

Comment: брограммер - это такой программист-раздолбай. Он постоянно отвлекается на всякую фигню, он неряшливый исполнитель во всех смыслах слова. А когда его спрашивают - почему работа не сделана, он отвечает: "Да братан, да расслабься ты, пойдём лучше по пивасику!".

Comment: Понял, спасибо. По-русски "brogrammer" будет "программист" :)
Шутка.
В русском языке нет аналогичного слова, самое близкое так и будет "раздолбай"

Comment: Если Вы допустили ошибку в Вашем ответе (такое бывает), я бы посоветовал один из двух вариантов: (1) Можно нажать на _Edit_ ссылку под ответом и отредактировать/изменить ответ; или (2) если ответ исправить невозможно, нажать на _Delete_ ссылку и совсем удалать ответ.

Comment: Никогда не слышал слова "бро" в русском языке.

Answer (score -2):

As far as i see brogrammer is brother+programmer. You cannot say it in one word in Russian. But you are welcome to create a neologism. Like a "браграммист" (брат+программист) or "братанграммист" (братан + программист), which is even better. "Bro" is more like "братан", than "брат".

Comment: minus one for these one, not that I'm strictly against proposing neologisms (though in context of this question I'm probably am, since author clearly asked about existing word). The main reason I downvote that, as Валерий have mentioned, those forms are not understandable.